# How to check if an element in a string array is empty?

Tags: java

How can I check if an element in a string array is empty? This is my example array:

```
private static String correct[] = new String[5];
    static {
        correct[1] = "some texT";
        correct[2] = "some texT3";
        correct[4] = "some texT2";
}
```

I can assign `null` to rest of elements, but I want to find another, better way to do this.
I found `isEmpty`, but it is available only on API 9 and above.

`if(correct[0].length() > 0)`
gives me a NPE.
`if(correct[0] != null` also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried the 'obvious':

```
if(correct[0] != null && correct[0].length() > 0) {
   //it is not null and it is not empty
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just compare it to `null`, which is the default value for an array of some object type.

```
if (correct[0] != null && correct[0].length() > 0)
```

The `&&` operator will only evaluate the right side if the left side is `true`, i.e. `correct[0]` isn't `null` and won't throw a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to check if a specific element in a specific position is empty (not only different from `null`, but from `""` too), the presented solutions won't be enough.

Java has a lot of ways to do this. Let's see some of them:

1. You can convert your array into a `List` (using [`Arrays's asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) method) and check the conditions through `contains()` method:

   ```
   import java.util.*;

   public class Test1 {

     private static boolean method1_UsingArrays(String[] array) {
      return Arrays.asList(array).contains(null) 
               || Arrays.asList(array).contains("");
     }
   }
   ```
2. It's also possible to use [`Collections's disjoint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29) method, to check whether two collections have elements in common or not:

   ```
   import java.util.*;

   public class Test2 {      

     private static String[] nullAndEmpty = {"", null};

     private static boolean method2_UsingCollectionsDisjoint(String[] array) {
      // disjoint returns true if the two specified collections have no elements in common.
      return !Collections.disjoint( //
        Arrays.asList(array), //
        Arrays.asList(nullAndEmpty) //
      );
     }

   }
   ```
3. If you're able to use **Java 8** (my favorite option), it's possible to make use of the new [Streams API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html).

   ```
   import java.util.stream.*;
   import java.util.*;

   public class Test3 {

     private static boolean method3_UsingJava8Streams(String[] array) {
      return Stream.of(array).anyMatch(x -> x == null || "".equals(x));
     }

   }
   ```

   Compared to the other options, this is even easier to handle in case you need to `trim` each of your strings (or call any of the other `String`'s methods):

   ```
   Stream.of(array).anyMatch(x -> x == null || "".equals(x.trim()));
   ```

---

Then, you can easily call and test them:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // Ok tests
  String[] ok = {"a", "b", "c"};

  System.out.println("Method 1 (Arrays - contains): " + method1_UsingArrays(ok)); // false
  System.out.println("Method 2 (Disjoint): " + method2_UsingCollectionsDisjoint(ok)); // false
  System.out.println("Method 3 (Java 8 Streams): " + method3_UsingJava8Streams(ok)); // false

  System.out.println("-------------------------------");

  // Nok tests
  String[] nok = {"a", null, "c"};

  System.out.println("Method 1 (Arrays - contains): " + method1_UsingArrays(nok)); // true
  System.out.println("Method 2 (Disjoint): " + method2_UsingCollectionsDisjoint(nok)); // true
  System.out.println("Method 3 (Java 8 Streams): " + method3_UsingJava8Streams(nok)); // true

  // Nok tests
  String[] nok2 = {"a", "", "c"};

  System.out.println("Method 1 (Arrays - contains): " + method1_UsingArrays(nok2)); // true
  System.out.println("Method 2 (Disjoint): " + method2_UsingCollectionsDisjoint(nok2)); // true
  System.out.println("Method 3 (Java 8 Streams): " + method3_UsingJava8Streams(nok2)); // true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you can't use isEmpty try to use Array.Contains(null) or try this small loop

```
for(int i = 0;i<=Array.length;i++){
  if(array[i] > 0 && array[i] != null){
     //yay its not null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had similar version where number of arguments could be bigger

```
if (Arrays.asList(new String[] {productId, productTitle, imageName, productPrice}).contains(null)) {
        return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just Use isAnyEmpty

```
org.apache.commons.lang3
StringUtils.isAnyEmpty(final CharSequence... css)
```